# Not getting stats analysis of binary column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, describe

I have a dataframe, 11 columns 18k rows. The last column is either a 1 or 0, but when I use .describe() all I get is

```
count     19020
unique        2
top           1
freq      12332
Name: Class, dtype: int64
```

as opposed to an actual statistical analysis with mean, std, etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Check the dtype of the last column. Looks like there's no column of type `int` or `float` in your df.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for `.describe()`? Can you produce a small, but complete example that exhibits the behaviour in question?

Comment: Based on the output, it looks like the last column parsed as an Object (String) Series. Hence, it is showing descriptive statistics pertain to String type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your numeric (0, 1) column is not being picked up automatically by `.describe()`, it might be because it's not actually encoded as an `int` dtype. You can see this in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) of the `.describe()` method, which tells you that the default `include` parameter is only for numeric types:

> None (default) : The result will include all numeric columns.

My suggestion would be the following:

```py
df.dtypes # check datatypes
df['num'] = df['num'].astype(int) # if it's not integer, cast it as such

df.describe(include=['object', 'int64']) # explicitly state the data types you'd like to describe
```

That is, first check the datatypes (I'm assuming the column is called `num` and the dataframe `df`, but feel free to substitute with the right ones). If this indicator/(0,1) column is indeed not encoded as `int`/integer type, then cast it as such by using `.astype(int)`. Then, you can freely use `df.describe()` and perhaps even specify columns of which data types you want to include in the description output, for more fine-grained control.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```py
# percentile list 
perc =[.20, .40, .60, .80] 
  
# list of dtypes to include 
include =['object', 'float', 'int']

data.describe(percentiles = perc, include = include)
```

where `data` is your dataframe (important point).

Since you are new to stack, I might suggest that you include some actual code (i.e. something showing how and on what you are using your methods). You'll get better answers